# How to change the display name of the website on google search

Tags: web, seo

I am making a website, but the client want the name of his website to be differently displayed by google.

His example is:

[image: Instagram search overview]

So here Instagram is named Instagram instead of instagram.com.

On our website the name is the same as the domain name. So here it would be like having instagram.com.

I search with Search engine optimization but didn't find any relevant topic related to this. They all speak about the page title and description which is not what I am searching for.

I also tried opensearch referencement. It didn't worked...

In hope someone have an idea of how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

PS: The website is written in svelte. (Maybe coming from there but idk)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the SEO tag states: GENERAL SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question here first.

Answer (score 1):

Create `svelte-head` inside svelte

```
<svelte:head>
  <title>Coding is Fun</title>
  <meta name="description" content="This is Description of Your Website" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Coding, Svelte, Anime" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Coding is Fun" />
  <meta
    property="og:description"
    content="This is Description of Your Website"
  />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/6Zbq3nV.png" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://codingisfun.xyz" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Coding is Fun" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
</svelte:head>
```

This is just an Example